# How to assign words to specific alphabets?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, character, nsdictionary, morse-code

I'm currently making an app similar to Morse Code, to encode, say A = hello, B = good by using `isEqualToString` method.

```
-(NSString*)checkWords :(NSString*)words{
NSString * letter;

if (([words isEqualToString:@"a"]) || ([words isEqualToString:@"A"])){
    letter = @"hello";        }
if (([words isEqualToString:@"b"]) || ([words isEqualToString:@"B"])){
    letter = @"good";        }
return letter;

}
```

By clicking the button below will generate the code:

```
- (IBAction)decodeBtn:(id)sender {

outputTextField.text = @"";
NSString * inputString = outputView.text;
int wordLength = [inputString length]; //gets a count of length

int i = 0;
while (i < wordLength) {

    unichar charToCheck = [inputString characterAtIndex:i];
    if (charToCheck != 32){ // checks to make sure its not a space

        NSString* words = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&charToCheck length:1];

        NSString * letter = [self checkWords:words];

        NSString * stringToAppend = outputTextField.text;
        if (letter != @""){
            outputTextField.text = [stringToAppend stringByAppendingString:letter];
        } else {
            // new line?
        }
        letter = nil;
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

I can get the alphabets to those words I needed.
I wonder which method I should use to decode the words back to the alphabets?
That is, when user input "hello good" and the output would be "A B"?

Thanks a lot.

If I write in this way, the app crashes:

[EncodeViewController copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

```
-(NSString*)checkWords :(NSString*)words{
NSString * letter;

if ([words isEqualToString:@"hello"]) letter = @"A";
if ([words isEqualToString:@"good"]) letter = @"B";

return letter;
}
```

Comment: The question is slightly hard to understand, but I think you could use an NSDictionary to build a map of words to letters, and lookup each word in the dictionary. If that doesn't answer your question, could you clarify the question a little?

Comment: @Tyler -- It sounds like he wants to translate to/from a [phonetic alphabet](http://www.history.navy.mil/faqs/faq101-1.htm).

Comment: Basically, if you couldn't rely on simply using the first character of the word, you'd use an NSDictionary as Tyler says, or something similar.  The NSDictionary would have "keys" of the words and "values" of the letters (probably best represented as a one-character NSString).

Comment: You could just reverse your code above -- `if ([word isEqualToString:@"apple"]) letter = @"A";`.  To simplify things use `lowercaseString` on "word" first, so you don't have to worry about whether it's "Apple" or "apple" or "APPLE".  And use `componentsSeparatedByString:@" "` to divide the incoming "sentence" into an NSArray of individual words.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks a lot, will try it now. So there's no need for me to use an NSDictionary in this case?

Comment: NSDictionary is a lot simpler/cleaner -- see my answer below.

Comment: `[EncodeViewController copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` indicates a problem elsewhere in your code.  Possibly you're trying to assign your EncodeViewController instance to a property with the `copy` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray* words = [sentence componentsSeparatedByString:@" '];
NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString* word in words) {
   word = [word lowercaseString];
   NSString* letter = [translationDict objectForKey:word];
   [output appendFormat:@"%@ ", letter];
}
```

To create your translationDict use:

```
NSDictionary* translationDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"apple", @"A", @"banana", @"B", @"chocho", @"C", @"dingodog", @"D", .... @"Z", nil];
```

You can then use the translation loop either direction (if your individual letters are separated by blanks), with the order of the keys and values reveresed in `translationDict`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry I'm really a newbie could you please tell me where should I place this code to?

Comment: I've edited my question as well, I believe its the code in `IBAction` that makes my app crashes.

Comment: To create the dictionary, you can use the new object literals, as in translationDict = @{ @"Arthur": @"A", @"Barbara": @"B", @"Cthulhu": @"C"};

Comment: +1 for sneaking in a Cthulhu reference, @Tyler, that was very clever.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own method and call it from somewhere with kinda such a content:

```
if ([userInput isEqualToString:@"apple banana"]) {
    NSMutableString * firstCharacters = [NSMutableString string];
    NSArray * words = [userInput componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    for (NSString * word in words) {
      if ([word length] > 0) {
        NSString * firstLetter = [word substringToIndex:1];
        [firstCharacters appendString:[firstLetter uppercaseString]];
//NSLog firstLetter and you get the result :)
      }
    }
}
```

Try it :)

Comment: sorry maybe I didnt say it clear enough. Actually its not the first letter of the word that I want to get. Should be "hey" = A, "yeah" = B, which those words are not really related to the characters